# Error when converting a site from Flex 3 to Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, migration, flex4

I'm moving a Flex 3 site to Flex 4, but when I run the application, it attempts to download a .swz file from Adobe, and gives the following error:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.1.0.604/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz halted - not permitted from http://localhost/Fl/CityGIS/main.swf
Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://localhost/Fl/CityGIS/main.swf cannot load data from http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.1.0.604/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz.
Failed to load RSL http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.1.0.604/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz
Failing over to RSL textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz
```

Following this is an attempt to download the same file from localhost.

Is there a way to configure the SDK to get these files, or an issue with the configuration of my application?

Answer (score 1):

I found I only had this problem when I using: -use-network=false, and I was attempting to run the html locally and the .swf was accessing locally files (outside the flex security free folders).

My workaround is to update sdks//frameworks/flex-config.xml (in the Flash Builder directory), and swap the order runtime shared paths: for example:

```
<runtime-shared-library-path>
    <path-element>libs/textLayout.swc</path-element>
    <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.1.0.604/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz</rsl-url>
    <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
    <rsl-url>textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz</rsl-url>
    <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>     
</runtime-shared-library-path>
```

TO:

```
<runtime-shared-library-path>
    <path-element>libs/textLayout.swc</path-element>
    <rsl-url>textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz</rsl-url>
    <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>     
    <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.1.0.604/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz</rsl-url>
    <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
</runtime-shared-library-path>
```

You'll have to do this for the other 5 or so entries.

Adobe should really look at this, and fix the problem.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Parmy

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm - generally this is because the site you are accessing does not contain a crossdomain.xml file.  However I can download it from [here](http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml).

Try adding this to your compiler options:  -use-network=false

Then clean and force build your app.

If that doesn't work, and just grasping for straws, but have you tried to [manually download](http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.1.0.604/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz) it and place it in your project lib space?

**Also, are you sure you are updated to Flex 4.1?**

I just checked my local KB (evernote) and mentioned that FireFox sometimes has an issue with caching, and that restarting FF solved it once for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the location it is using for the textLayout swc 
http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.1.0.604/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz

*redirects* to

/pub/swz/flex/4.1.0.15186/textLayout_1.1.0.601.swf

and the cross domains policy is not happy about that.

I think this points to an issue with the version of the sdk that you are using. You can go into `sdks/<FRAMEWORK_VERSION>/frameworks/flex-config.xml` (*in the Flash Builder directory*) and see exactly how the runtime shared library path is configured for textLayout.swc. This is what I have for `flex_sdk_4.1.0.15186`:

```
<!-- TextLayout SWC -->    
<runtime-shared-library-path>
  <path-element>libs/textLayout.swc</path-element>
  <rsl-url>textLayout_1.1.0.601.swf</rsl-url>    
  <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>    
  <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.1.0.15186/textLayout_1.1.0.601.swf</rsl-url>
  <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
</runtime-shared-library-path>
```

I suggest try switching to the latest 4.1 sdk and recompiling.